# Simultaneous recursion over multiple parameter packs

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible in C++ to simultaneously recurse over multiple (in my case two) parameter packs? How?

To give a better idea of exactly what I'm asking, I currently have a class template as follows:

```
template<template<typename> class C, typename... Rest>
class Inherit {};
template<template<typename> class C, typename T, typename... Rest>
class Inherit<C, T, Rest...> :
    public C<T>,
    public Inherit<C, Rest...>
{
};
```

I'm using this class template in another class which takes a parameter pack `Ts` to have that class inherit multiple times from a templated interface. For example:

```
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
    ...
};

template<typename... Ts>
class Example :
    public Inherit<Interface, Ts...>
{
};
```

Now, what I would like to do is this:

```
template<typename T, const char* N>
class Interface
{
    ...
};

template<typename... Ts, const char*... Ns>
class Example :
    public Inherit<Interface, Ts..., Ns...>
{
};
```

I need a templated `Inherit` class that can recurse and pick an element off of both the `Ts` and the `Ns` parameter pack at once (assuming that parameter pack `Ts` and `Ns` have the same length).  I'm not versed enough in template programming to know if this is even possible?

Comment: What's the point in making an explicit chain of inheritance? Why not just `template<template<typename> class C, typename... Rest>
class Inherit : public C<Rest>... {};` without a template specialization?

Comment: `Inherit` has a `typename... Rest`.  That only excepts types.  `Inherit` would have to be changed to look like `template<template<typename> class C, typename T, typename... Rest, const char*... Ns>`

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that you don't need this `Inherit` class template based on the examples you gave. Here's how I'd write your first example:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Interface
{
    ...
};

template<typename... Ts>
class Example : public Interface<Ts>...
{
};
```

and your second example:

```cpp
template<typename T, const char* N>
class Interface
{
};

template<typename, const char*...>
class Example;

template<typename... Ts, const char*... Ns>
class Example<std::tuple<Ts...>, Ns...> : public Interface<Ts, Ns>...
{
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. This even simplified my initial solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`template <typename... Ts, const char*... Ns> class Example;` is wrong.

You might want something like (no recursion)

```
template<typename T, const char* N>
class Interface 
{
    // ...
};

template<typename T, typename Names> class Example;

template<typename... Ts, const char*... Ns>
class Example<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::integer_sequence<const char*, Ns...>> :
    public: Interface<Ts, Ns>...
{
};
```

`Interface<Ts, Ns>...` requires that both packs have the same size.